# How can I fill whole space with text in Textview?

Tags: android, textview, android-cardview

this link shows what I want to do.

http://webstyleguide.com/wsg3/figures/8-typography/8-7-650.jpg

I wanted to justify the text in TextView Thanks!

And this is my TextView xml:

```
 <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:maxLines="999999999"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/myTitle" />
```

But I can't fill whole space of TextView with texts. Actually, I want to remove empty lines in each lines and I want to fill them by texts.

Comment: Describe better what do you want. Or post the current state and your ideal state, you want.

Comment: I fixed it Thanks. Jantursky!